# What kind of tower was Ales Dudar referring to in "The Tower"?

Tags: poetry, belarusian-language, like-water-like-fire, ales-dudar

*The Tower* by Ales Dudar contains the following:

> The tower sleeps? What is it dreaming?
> It rises, gloomy, like a ghost.
> A prison here? A belly seeming?
> Who is there that can guess its past?
> ...
> And now, today, these men in
> Boots tramp the drawbridge-plank once more

What kind of tower is this? And what kind of men are these? Are these workmen or soldiers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it was before we cannot know. It is said very clearly.

Now it serves as a radio station. Or, rather, soon will serve:

> І сёння к вежы прывязалі
> драты ўстрывожаную даль...
> О, прадзеды, каб вы пазналі
> антэны стынучую сталь!
>
> Today they bound to the tower
> the wires of disturbed distance.
> O Ancestors, if you only could see
> a cold steel of an antenna.

(sorry for a sloppy translation). This pretty much implies that the men in boots are workers.